# UnboundLocalError at /blog/search/ local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, solr, django-views, django-haystack, django-settings

I am trying to set up django-haystack with solr,,,but I just keep get the error:

> UnboundLocalError at /blog/search/ local variable 'cd' referenced
>   before assignment

I think might be my

> views.py

something wrong,,,.
my app name "blog",,and there are already several blogs on that
[image]

after I add core blog there shows 8 docs

[image]

here is my

> settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'e8m%vu0d&_0o-u*0@^*oh-2k4+j8_$c@qdj@)p353s%5p)2bx^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'taggit',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'haystack',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'



HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/blog'
    },
}
```

I have put schema in schema.xml

[image]

my

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')


class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

my (guess something wrong here??)

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db.models import Count

from taggit.models import Tag

from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm, SearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

.........

def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                     'cd': cd,
                                                     'results': results,
                                                     'total_results': total_results})
```

my

> search.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% if "query" in request.GET %}
        <h1>Posts containing "{{ cd.query }}"</h1>
        <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}</h3>
        {% for result in results %}
            {% with post=result.object %}
                <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
                {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
            {% endwith %}
        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <p><a href="{% url "blog:post_search" %}">Search again</a></p>
    {% else %}
        <h1>Search for posts</h1>
        <form action="." method="get">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed


urlpatterns = [
        .....
        url(r'^search/$', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
]
```

when I click the blog/search it just show the error

[image]

> error message

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/search/

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 3.4.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'haystack')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/korekyourin/books/djexample/mysite/blog/views.py" in post_search
  112.                                                      'cd': cd,

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /blog/search/
Exception Value: local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `post_search` view you're defining `cd` only if the `form.is_valid()`.

When the GET request doesn't contains the `query` variable, you don't have the `cd` variable, that's why the error is happening.

Try to indent the `return render()` to the is_valid() conditional.

Comment: thank you,,after I  indent the return render() to the is_valid() conditional.and put else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,}) outside the is_valid() conditional,,,it can work

Answer (score 3):

first, thanks for Andre answer to me,,,here is my new

> views.py

```
.......

def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
        return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                         'cd': cd,
                                                         'results': results,
                                                         'total_results': total_results})


    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,})
```